# Служба windows С#

Tags: c#, служба

Есть приложение написанное на C#, все параметры приложения прописаны в config.ini. Хочу это приложение переделать в службу что бы исключить человеческий фактор. Служба будет крутится на сервере 24/7. Мне необходимо что бы она отрабатывала каждый день к примеру в 15:00. Я самоучка и много не знаю в C#. Подскажите, возможно ли оставить что бы служба получала параметры из config.ini или все параметры придется зашивать в код? Как реализовать отработку каждый день в 15:00, в while и проверку на текущее время или есть что то более удобное или правильней?

Comment: Тут скорее планировщик задач стоит использовать, а не службу писать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задачу можно решить с использованием одного из шедулера задач для .net — таких как [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) или [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/)

Пример реализации запуска задания каждый день в 15:00 с помощью Quartz .net:

```
public class MyJob : Quartz.IJob
{
    public void CreateJob()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<MyJob>().Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
            (s =>
                s.WithIntervalInHours(24) 
                    .OnEveryDay()
                    .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(15, 0))
            )
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        // Выполнение основной задачи
    }
}
```

Постановка задачи:

```
  MyJob job = new MyJob();
  job.CreateJob();
```

Comment: Прошу по подробней. Я подключаю к проекту Quartz, компилю приложение. Что после этого, в автозагрузку его и оно в фоне будет крутится и отрабатывать? Или как это работает?

Comment: Если речь идет о сервисе — то у него прописать `Startup Type: Automatic`. Если о консольном приложении — то можно прописать его на запуск в Windows ТaskSheduler'е, но, вероятно, лучше рассмотреть вариант переделки этого приложения на сервис. 
  Далее, в событии сервиса `OnStart`, ставим нашу задачу:
`protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
      MyJob job = new MyJob();
     job.CreateJob();
}`

Comment: Павел спасибо. Уточнение, правильно ли я понял, что ваш пример касается именно службы? Будет ли служба читать файл ini, для этого надо прописать на него абсолютные пути?

Comment: Про чтение файла с настройками в моем коде ничего нет. Для работы с настройками рекомендую использовать App.config (в студии контекстное меню над проектом -> Add New Item -> Application Configuration File): `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
    <add key="MySettings" value="Test" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>` и чтение из этого файла: `string s = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySettings"];`. В этом случае вам не придется заботиться о пути к файлу конфигурации.