# Ежедневный запуск программы

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Есть приложение написанное на c# в visual studio. Каждый день я его запускаю в ручную в определенное время. Можно ли как-то это автоматизировать?

Comment: Самый простой вариант - планировщик заданий Windows, или Cron в Unix. Если хотите программно, то хм, создайте службу...

Comment: Я задавал подобный вопрос, в итоге переписал приложение под службу. Вот ссылка на вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704338/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%B0-windows-%D0%A1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Windows**

Делается это через Планировщик заданий Windows.

Панель управления -> Система и безопасность -> Администрирование -> Планировщик заданий -> Создать задачу

Введите имя задачи, перейдите на вкладку "Действия" и нажмите "Создать" - введите имя вашей программы и список аргументов. Во вкладке "Условия", если у вас ноутбук, уберите галочку "Запускать только при питании от электросети". Нажмите "ОК" для завершения.

**Системы класса UNIX**

Используйте [`cron`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

[Пример создания задачи в Ubuntu Server](https://interface31.ru/tech_it/2011/03/cron-tochno-po-raspisaniyu.html)

Answer (score 0):

в визуал студио заходишь в средства -> диспечер пакетов nuGet->управление пакетами для решения
оттуда устанавливаешь в свое решение TaskScheduler
дальше
что то типа этого(взял с инглиша вот ссылка если интересно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks)

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;

class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      // Get the service on the local machine
      using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
      {
         // Create a new task definition and assign properties
         TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
         td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

         // Create a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
         td.Triggers.Add(new DailyTrigger { DaysInterval = 2 });

         // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
         td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.log", null));

         // Register the task in the root folder
         ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Test", td);

         // Remove the task we just created
         ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask("Test");
      }
   }
}
```